# Can this $2\times 2$ block matrix has only real eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given real square matrices (possibly) non-symmetric $A$ and $B$, can we find conditions where the eigen values of below matrix are all real?
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B
\\
-B &A\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: If this real $2n\times 2n$ matrix represents the complex $n\times n$ matrix $C = A+iB$, then it would suffice for $C$ to be hermitian. You can check this happens if and only if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew-symmetric. If you say that $A$ cannot be symmetric, then offhand I don't know any simple criterion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The matrices are all real, and yeah A and B may be non-symmetric.

Comment: Slightly more generally, an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of your matrix is an eigenvalue of $A + i B$ or of $A - i B$.  So you want $A \pm i B$ to have real eigenvalues.